# Kotlin: How to deal with 'protected' property exposes its internal return type

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, class-visibility

Having a base class I would like it and its descendent class be visible only internally:

```
internal abstract class BaseClass
internal open class Class_A: BaseClass()
internal open class Class_B: Class_A()
```

In place where the list of `Class_A` (may also contains `Class_B` in it), would like to make it protected for its own descendent class to access this list

```
open class User {
    // got error: 'protected' property exposes its internal return type" 
    protected var class_A_list: List<Class_A>? = null
}

class User_descendent: User() {
    // can access the class_A_list
}
```

How to let the descendent class access the instance of some "internal" class?

Answer (score 5):

The above error is protecting the `internal` classes to be accessed by other classes which are not in the same module of the internal class. If it was allowed, then you can't guarantee that the class `User` would be only inherited by the classes in the same module.

So if you want to make the `class_A_list` protected, you have to make the `User` class `internal`. By doing so, it will guarantee that, `User` will be inherited by the classes which is in the same module. The following should be fine:

```
internal open class User {
   protected var class_A_list: List<Class_A>? = null
}
```

Comment: True, but than you have to make `User_descendent` internal too, otherwise you run in: 'public' subclass exposes its internal supertype 'User'

Comment: @stinepike thanks! but can not make the "User" internal, it is part of the lib and intend for being extended outside. wondering why kotlin has this restriction, or has a way for doing so.

Comment: @lannyf, Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve. May be there is better way to do that instead of using chains of internals. If you can describe your use-case scenario more clearly (like which part are external libraries, which you must have to make internals and why, etc.)

Comment: sure, it is a lib, the class User is open and allow to be extended internal and external.   In the User it has list<T> that T is defined internal  in the User's package (dont want to expose the T to outside of the package, but still want User to accessed outside).

Comment: So is this a 3rd party library or a library you are creating? if it later, then I think you may consider changing the design?

Comment: If you want your library users to be able subclass this User class and have access to its `Class_A`-related property, then `Class_A` cannot be internal. Instead, you could define a public interface that `Class_A` implements and make the `protected` list have that type.

Comment: The User should be allowed to extend but not required to access the internal class_A_list in the of the case for the lib user, so it could be private in User which works. The only problem is for an internal derived User_descendent which needs to access the parent User's class_A_list, then making it protect is not allowed here.  I guess need to consider some redesign or something move to an interface in order to make it work. Thank you all!